# Can I store a string in a $_SESSION? (retain a string through many redirects)

Tags: php

I have an InstaGram app and I want to be able to set a custom hashtag in the input field, how could I go about doing this?

Here's how the site works step by step

The user goes here and by default the hashtag will be = "#starcraft2"
http://cinicraft.com/InstaCraft/example.php

but when the user clicks InstaCraft, that will then take them to -> example.php then redirect to -> callback.php

So here's the code for the input to set your custom hashtag in callback.php:

```
    <form action="example.php" method="get">

    <li>Custom Hashtag:<p> <input type="text" name="hashGET" size="45"> </p></li>

<input type="submit"></form>

</form>


user clicks submit and Custom Hashtag will be GET'ed to example.php
```

As soon as example.php opens, I successfully retain the custom hashtag like so:

```
$hashGET = $_GET["hashGET"];   // <- INSIDE EXAMPLE.PHP
```

And here is where my problem arises, example.php will then automatically redirect to callback.php. callback.php is what actually sends the custom hashtag to InstaGram and that's where the images come from.

But how can I get example.php -> to send $hashGET to -> callback.php? This is what I have to work with:

```
$name = $_GET["hashGET"];  

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken']) && !empty($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken'])) {
    header('Location: callback.php');
    die();
}

// Instantiate the API handler object
$instagram = new Instagram($config);
$instagram->openAuthorizationUrl();
```

Comment: either pass your tag as a GET parameter when redirecting to `callback.php` or store it in your session in `example.php` doing `$_SESSION["myInstagramHash"] = $hashGet;` and retrieve it in `callback.php` with `$myHash = $_SESSION["myInstagramHash"];`

Comment: you can redirect with the hashtag provided via get header('Location: callback.php?hashGET='.$name);, then you can access $_GET['hashGET'] from the callback.php

Answer (score 0):

Why do you redirect? Simply put your code into a function and call that.

This also saves you one server-browser roundtrip.

Comment: I'm forced to authorize with Instagram with a redirect URI